# If $\mbox{tr} (A^tA)=0$ then $A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, matrix-norms

I am stuck at this proof. It's an if and only if, for all $m \times n$ real matrices. From one side I've figured it out, but for this side, if $\mbox{tr}(A^tA)=0$ I just got that $$\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}a_{ji}=0$$ but from here I can't see why $A=0$.

Comment: The expansion you wrote out is for tr(A^2), not tr(A^t A). Try writing out tr(BA) first and then take B=A^t.

Comment: $A^TA$ is positive semi-definite so it is diagonalizable with nonnegative eigenvalues. Trace is the sum of all eigenvalues. Conclude that all eigenvalues are 0 and hence $A^TA = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $A = (a_{ij})$ and $A^T = (b_{ij})$ where $b_{ij} = a_{ji}$ and hence the diagonal elements of the product look like
$$
[A^T A]_{ii}
 = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{ki}
 = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} a_{ik}
 = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}^2
$$
and since the trace of $A^T A$ is zero, then all the diagonal elements must be zero, thus each element of the sum must be zero as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The matrix $A^TA$ is positive semi-definite (why?) and the trace is the sum of all the eigenvalues.